# @AppStorage is not updating colorScheme environment variable instantly

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a `SettingsView` to let the user change the color scheme for the app, I store the user selection using `@AppStorage`, then i adjust the `preferredColorScheme` for the `SettingsView` using the value from `@AppStorage`, everything is working good because I change the view appearance based on the `@AppStorage` value and not the `colorScheme` environment property, if i try to do so, it wont work. `preferredColorScheme` is not being updated when `AppStorage` value changes, but when i exit the view and open it again.

EDIT: for some reason, it is working perfectly on the preview but not in the simulator itself.

```
import SwiftUI

struct SettingsView: View {
    @State private var isPresentPrivacyPolicy = false
    @State private var isPresentTermsOfUse = false
    @AppStorage("selectedColorScheme") private var selectedColorScheme = "Light"

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if selectedColorScheme == "Dark" {
                Theme.darkBackground
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
            } else {
                Theme.lightBackground
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
            }
            List {
                Section {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "doc.text.magnifyingglass")
                        Button("Privacy Policy") {
                            isPresentPrivacyPolicy = true
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(.plain)
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "doc.plaintext")
                        Button("Terms of use") {
                            isPresentTermsOfUse = true
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(.plain)
                    }
                } header: {
                    Text("About")
                        .font(.headline)
                }
                .listRowBackground(selectedColorScheme == "Dark" ? Theme.listDarkBackground : Theme.listLightBackground)
                Section {
                    Picker("Color Scheme", selection: $selectedColorScheme) {
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "sun.max")
                            Text("Light")
                        }
                        .tag("Light")
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "moon")
                            Text("Dark")
                        }
                        .tag("Dark")
                    }
                } header: {
                    Text("App")
                        .font(.headline)
                }
                .listRowBackground(selectedColorScheme == "Dark" ? Theme.listDarkBackground : Theme.listLightBackground)
            }
            .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
        }
        .preferredColorScheme(selectedColorScheme == "Dark" ? .dark : .light)
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresentTermsOfUse) {
            NavigationStack {
                WebView(url: URL(string: "example.com")!)
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                    .navigationTitle("App")
                    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresentPrivacyPolicy) {
            NavigationStack {
                WebView(url: URL(string: "example.com")!)
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                    .navigationTitle("App")
                    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Settings_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SettingsView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of the [`preferredColorScheme()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/View/preferredColorScheme(_:)) modifier might be not inside the usage case that Apple intends it for:

> A common use for this modifier is to create side-by-side **previews** of the same view with light and dark appearances

and

> If you need to detect the color scheme that currently applies to a view, read the `colorScheme` environment value

So you are trying to do it in reverse.

*Solution*:
**If you are really sure you want a separate color scheme for your app, keep those variables separate from the OS's color scheme. Name your app's color scheme differently, and don't use `preferredColorScheme` modifier.**