# preferredColorScheme is not changing the app's color scheme instantly

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, darkmode

I am working on a hybrid UIKit/SwiftUI application. Almost all the interfaces are in SwiftUI. Of course we want to allow the user to toggle between light and dark modes. On the app's settings page I have a toggle button linked to a UserDefault. I can toggle the button and verify that the UserDefault dose indeed change appropriately. At the bottom of the settings view I call `.preferredColorScheme(isDarkMode ? .dark : .light)` but when isDarkMode toggles, nothing happens. I have to completely kill and reload the app before the new scheme takes effect. The color scheme dose change instantly in the SwiftUI preview, just not in the app.

Hypothetically as soon as I toggle the button the entire app should transition to light/dark mode.

**SettingsView**

```
struct SettingsView: View {
    
    
    @AppStorage("isDarkMode") private var isDarkMode = false
        
    var body: some View {
        List{
            Section(header: Text("App Settings")
                .font(.subheadline.weight(.medium))
                .foregroundColor(.white) )
            {
                ListItemView(title: "Dark Mode", subTitle: isDarkMode ? "ON" : "OFF") {

                    Spacer()
                    Toggle("", isOn: $isDarkMode)
                        .frame(width: 30)
                        .padding(.trailing)

                }
                
            }
            
        }
        .navigationTitle("Settings")
        .preferredColorScheme(isDarkMode ? .dark : .light)        
    }
}
```

**AppDelegate**

```
@AppStorage("isDarkMode") private var isDarkMode = false


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

        let gettingStarted = GettingStartedView(featureData: FeatureData())
                .preferredColorScheme(isDarkMode ? .dark : .light)
            
            let rootVC = UIHostingController(rootView: gettingStarted)
            
            window?.rootViewController = rootVC
            window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Comment: Why not simply follow the device scheme?  Anyway, your problem is that a change to an AppStorage property won't trigger the code in `didFinishLaunching` to run again.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76881756/16157878

Comment: @Paulw11 why would it need to?

Comment: Why would it need to run again?  Because you are creating an instance of your `GettingStartedView` and modifying it with `preferredColorScheme`. When you change your color scheme setting you need to create a new instance of that view with the new preferred color scheme. This doesn't happen it's your current code.

Comment: @Paulw11 I was under the impression that simply setting the `preferredColorScheme` would instantly change the scheme for, at the very least, the view I am on and any "child" view's there in.

Comment: Yes, but it is only set once, when your app launches. Changing the value of an AppStorage property isn't going to run the code `didFinishLaunching` again. That code only runs once, when your app finishes launching. Your AppDelegate isn't a SwiftUI view.